# issue while trying to exit a loop

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

i have a switch with cases and in one I have a for loop with several if's, I want to go to the menu(get out of this case) if the user gives a "b" for no, but it doesn't do anything with the do{}, while(exiting =! false), the program keeps running, I can't use breaks,
It looks something like this:

```
case 'E': { 
    bool exiting = true;
    do {
        cout << "For how many minutes do you want to book the service? ";
        cin >> minutes;
        for(int i = 0; i < cantServ; i++) {
           if(minutes > listaServicio[position]->getMaxTime()){ 
               cout<< "the machine has a time limit, do you want to book it for 
               less time? (a= yes, b = no) ";
                cin>>anwser; 
                if(answer== 'a'){
                    cout << "how many minutes do you want to book? "; 
                    cin >> minutes; 
                  } else { 
                    exiting = false; }               
                 }  
              }
           } while(exiting != false);
          
           break;
           }
```

Comment: Indentation is whacky and may be hiding mis-matched braces from you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add a break after `exiting = false;` so that you jump out of the inner for loop and straight to the while-do, which should then exit.

Comment: thank you for ansering! I have tried that but still doesn't seem to affect in anything :(

Comment: Could you reformat your sample code and maybe try a normal while loop instead of a do-while (I see no reason to use a do-while here, since you init exiting to true right before the first run anyway) and a normal while is much easier to read imo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use `break`, you can instead expand the `for` loop condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cantServ && exiting != false; i++) {
```

That way, you're always checking the state of `exiting` and the loop can terminate as desired once you set `exiting` to `false`.

Comment: the logic sounds like it works but i have tried adding that extended loop condition and it still runs to the other conditions after that for loop :(